# curl transaction fails from Heroku

Tags: curl, heroku

I'm trying to pull a database backup from Heroku via Amazon in curl and I keep getting empty files. The basic form of the transaction is:

```
 curl -o latest-dump `heroku pgbackups:url`
```

Of course, the back ticks are to run this as a command to dynamically insert the long url. I gave up on doing this in the CMD and am attempting to do this in cygwin since at least it understands the back ticks.

I can run this command successfully in my personal Mac so I'm stumped as to why it's failing to provide a file as expected.

When I run the curl command with the verbose option and the only indication is a 400 Bad Request which makes me think the output of the heroku command is broken. So I copied the output of the heroku command and attempted it:

```
 curl -v -o latest.dump 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/hkpgbackups/app28197640@heroku.com/xxxx.dump?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJSCBEZJRDOTGNGZQ&Expires=1410954117&Signature=pOgPFgADIvrWT%2FfBT6MXQFxhWhc%3D'
```

Its output is below but I'm not seeing an error?

```
 * STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x6000565f0; line 1028 (connection #-5000)
 * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
 *   Trying 54.231.14.80...
 * STATE: CONNECT => WAITCONNECT handle 0x6000565f0; line 1076 (connection #0)
   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to      s3.amazonaws.com (54.231.14.80) port 443 (#0)
 * successfully set certificate verify locations:
 *   CAfile: /usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
   CApath: none
 * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
 } [data not shown]
 * STATE: WAITCONNECT => PROTOCONNECT handle 0x6000565f0; line 1189 (connection #0)
 * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
 { [data not shown]
 * SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
 { [data not shown]
 * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
 { [data not shown]
 * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
 } [data not shown]
 * SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
 } [data not shown]
 * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
 } [data not shown]
 * SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
 { [data not shown]
 * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
 { [data not shown]
 * SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / AES128-SHA
 * Server certificate:
 *        subject: C=US; ST=Washington; L=Seattle; O=Amazon.com Inc.; CN=s3.amazonaws.com
 *        start date: 2014-04-12 00:00:00 GMT
 *        expire date: 2015-04-13 23:59:59 GMT
 *        subjectAltName: s3.amazonaws.com matched
 *        issuer: C=US; O=VeriSign, Inc.; OU=VeriSign Trust Network; OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10; CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
 *        SSL certificate verify ok.
 * STATE: PROTOCONNECT => DO handle 0x6000565f0; line 1208 (connection #0)
 > GET /hkpgbackups/app28197640@heroku.com/xxxx.dump?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJSCBEZJRDOTGNGZQ&Expires=1410954117&Signature=pOgPFgADIvrWT%2FfBT6MXQFxhWhc%3D      HTTP/1.1
 > User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
 > Host: s3.amazonaws.com
 > Accept: */*
 >
 * STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x6000565f0; line 1281 (connection #0)
 * STATE: DO_DONE => WAITPERFORM handle 0x6000565f0; line 1407 (connection #0)
 * STATE: WAITPERFORM => PERFORM handle 0x6000565f0; line 1420 (connection #0)
 * HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
 < HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
 < x-amz-request-id: A4C8B6D374B54A17
 < x-amz-id-2: X52WUUKWvGDZ+FCPh2fGtecBY2zEeZHmelLDCzuXY1q9G7sBoR0jO/BpS15WP9nsUTDDiRQEvR8=
 < Content-Type: application/xml
 < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 < Date: Wed, 17 Sep 2014 12:26:01 GMT
 * Server AmazonS3 is not blacklisted
 < Server: AmazonS3
 <
 { [data not shown]
 * STATE: PERFORM => DONE handle 0x6000565f0; line 1590 (connection #0)
 100   333    0   333    0     0   2221      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2752
 * Connection #0 to host s3.amazonaws.com left intact
 * Expire cleared
```

Is there something special about that URL that's fighting me here? It does seem to change its signature? Help me see what I'm missing here, thanx, sam

Comment: I suspect this is a shell escaping issue. Did you try something like: `curl -v -o dump -L "$(heroku pgbackups:url)"`

Comment: I'm sure you are right, thx. Why else does it work in OS X? Your example should work but the curl log indicates a 400 (bad request) which indicates something is muffed on the URL, even though it is a fresh instance of the backup. It only works if I paste the url within quotes. Without the quotes, I get a 403 (Forbidden) error.

Comment: Looking at it again, there are additional special characters in the URL that need to be escaped (e.g. `&`). Single quotes do not interpret special characters, but double quotes will.

Comment: Thank you for looking again. The trick is that enclosing it in single quotes would eliminate any substitution of a $URL value. I cannot find where I can wrap quotes after interpolation?

Comment: You need to escape the special characters with something like `sed` or use `eval` to create a single-quoted string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should have worked as is but a friend looked it over and found that the URL was being munged by the heroku.bat program. Because the Heroku URL is very long, the Windows side kept adding a carriage return in the URL. THus I would get 400 errors from Amazon. Presumably if it was heroku.sh it should work without modification but this now works within cygwin:

curl -o latest.dump -l "$(heroku.bat pgbackups:url | dos2unix)"

Thanks to Naaman Newbold for not giving up on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I pasted the URL as is in Google Chrome and it downloaded the file for me.